# Euclidean or Minkowski Metric for Clustering Spatio-Temporal Data?

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, data-analysis

> **Question:**
>   when does using Minkowski metric $\quad\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2}\quad $for clustering $(x,y,z,t)$ data yield better results than using Euclidean metric $\quad\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2}\ $?

I am asking because I haven't seen the Minkowski metric being mentioned or used in any article dealing with clustering of spatio-temporal data, especially not in training neural networks to classify motion patterns and I wonder how tolerable it is to use a wrong mathematical model for physical reality.

Comment: Re: "I wonder how tolerable it is to use a wrong mathematical model for physical reality" -- Do you know of examples that actually deal with relativistic spacetime data, so that the use of an Euclidean metric would be wrong? (Or do I misunderstand your question, and are you asking for examples that use the Minkowski metric for non-relativistic problems?)

Comment: this minus sign makes no sense without introducing the speed of light and applying relativistic dynamics; what are going to do when $x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2$ becomes negative? have an imaginary distance?

Comment: @JulesLamers you are right, I am looking for examples that use the Minkowski metric for non-relativistic problems.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker if my question was more about the qualitative decision between + and - when dealing with 3D data that has a time-stamp; should that be interpreted as vectors in Euclidean space or in Minkowski space? When the data comes from physical measurements, then the sum can't be negative.

Comment: when can't the sum be negative? imagine events which are temporally separated but not spatially.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: ok, you convinced me; interpreting t as time in a dataset isn't a good idea.